# Internet explorer 8 uses mobile settings

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My website seems to be working just fine. Only when I view it in IE8 it seems to use my mobile settings. I can see it because the navigation is the mobile navigation. I was wondering what could be the cause of this. This is the URL: http://www.embo-architecten.be.

Hope you guys can help out!

Answer (score 0):

As Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support media queries, the mobile layout is shown (due to the mobile first architecture of Bootstrap). You can add support for media queries in Internet Explorer 8 by adding a JavaScript polyfill called Respond.js

You need to add something like this to the `<head>` section

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

See [Internet Explorer 8 and Respond.js](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-respondjs) in Bootstrap's documentation for background information on this. Its [basic template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template) includes this, next to a shim that adds support for html5 elements in Internet Explorer 8.